# Passing comma delimited list as parameter to IN clause for decimal field in DB2

Tags: db2, procedure, in-clause

I want to pass a comma delimited list of values as a parameter to a query..
But its shows

*Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.18.60*

My code is given below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUSTOMER_DET(IN customers Varchar(20))
LANGUAGE SQL
.....
....
..
update customers set status = 'Y' where c_id in (customers );
...
...
```

Comment: You can only do this natively in a couple of RDBMSs, and DB2 isn't one of them (that I'm aware of).  The usual solution is to create some sort of stored procedure that splits a string (or array parameter, which is different than the actual list of parameters, but the type is rare) and yields the list or a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `PureXML` by parsing an XML document into a dynamic table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUSTOMER_DET(IN customers XML )
LANGUAGE SQL
. . . 
. . .
update customers set status = 'Y' where c_id in 
( 
 SELECT id 
 FROM XMLTABLE(
 '/customers/customer' PASSING customers 
 COLUMNS id VARCHAR(20) PATH '@id') AS custlist 
)
```

Then pass the customer IDs using this XML

```
<customers>
<customer id="joecustomer"/>
<customer id="frankcustomer"/>
</customers>
```

Comment: you can also transform a comma separated list to this by prefixing with `<customers><customer id="` post-fixing with `/></customers>` and replacing each comma with `"/><customer id="` like this: `PASSING '<customers><customer id=" || replace(@instring,',','"/><customer id="') || '/></customers>'`

Answer (score 0):

By using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** keyword, am solved the issue.

```
DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(20000);
...
..
SET STMT = 'update customers set status = 'Y' where c_id in ('||CHAR(pen_codes)||')';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT;
```

But i can't able to use this **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** for a **SELECT INTO** query..

```
SET STMT = 'select sum(requests) into total_request from customers where c_id in ('||CHAR(pen_codes)||')'
```